# Build fails when ZipAligning

Tags: exception, build, xamarin.android

I have just installed Xamarin along with the plugin for Visual studio 2013 professional.

Now I have a problem when I open an Android project and I build it, it throws an error.

```
System.Exception: Build started.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\Asad Shafique\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\App6.App6-Signed-Unaligned.apk obj\Debug\android\bin\App6.App6.apk androiddebugkey 
The specified task executable location "C:\Users\Asad Shafique\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid.
Build FAILED.
```

What would the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Android SDK folder C:\Users\Asad Shafique\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0 and copy "zipalign.exe" to C:\Users\Asad Shafique\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools.

Google has changed their paths in the latest SDK.

[Xamarin forum discussion](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19331/specified-task-executable-location-zipalign-exe-is-invalid)